# Setup Ubuntu Router with a subnet

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, iptables, ip-forward

I'd like to set up a private subnetwork within my home network. I've already read a few articles about this, but I'm not sure how exactly the `/etc/network/interface` file has to be set up under Linux. A Linux client should serve as a router between the DSL router and the other clients in the private subnetwork. The clients are connected to the router via eth0 interface and the router is connected to the home wifi via wlan0 interface.

[Picture of the setup is displayed here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Gvq.png)

The ubuntu router iptable entries are:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
```

The ubuntu router `/etc/network/interface` file looks like:

```
    auto wlan0
    iface wlan0 inet dhcp
     wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

    allow-hotplug eth0
    iface eth0 inet static
     address 10.0.0.1
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     broadcast 10.0.0.255
     gateway 192.168.0.1 (Wifi Router IP)
     dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1
```

I also enabled ip4 forwarding.
The one for the ubuntu clients looks like:

```
 allow-hotplug
    iface eth0 net static
     address 10.0.0.2 (changed for each client)
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     broadcast 10.0.0.255
     gateway 10.0.0.1 (Ubuntu Router IP)
```

Using `curl www.google.de` on the clients gives me `Could not resolve host: www.google.de` and ping ends with `Destination Host Unreachable`

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? It matters because things changed as of 18.04 and netplan. Don't declare a gateway for eth0, it is the gateway.

Comment: The ubuntu router is 16.04 and the clients are raspberry pis running with HypriotOs. They use cloud-init but I disabled it.

Comment: O.K. great (I am still on 16.04 because I hate netplan). Remove this line `gateway 192.168.0.1 (Wifi Router IP)`. And then can you ping via IP addresses? I'll have to think more about DNS (because for my box the router is also the DNS).

Comment: Yes I can ping every host within the subnet as well as the wifi router. Did you already solve the DNS stuff? There is a keyword `dns-nameservers` for the `/etc/network/interface` file but I don't know if I have to insert it in both files, at the client and server.

Comment: in my case, my ubuntu server router box is also the DNS and the DHCP server, so it tells the clients that it is also the DNS as part of granting their IP lease. Yes in the client, no in the server, as per the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your wlan0 interface is DHCP, so you have to look if it requests, and gets, a DNS server IP with its lease. You can do this by simply testing lookups from the router computer to see if they work. More precisely look at the request and the granted lease. 
If you are using the default `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` file then you should see something like this:

```
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
       domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
       netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
       rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers;
```

where you can see part of the request of for `domain-name-servers`. You can modify the request and/or override things in this file. The granted lease should be in `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.wlan0.leases` and you should see a DNS line therein.

Second, your client computers are using static IP addresses so you have to tell them what to use as a DNS. You need to add that to their `/etc/network/interface files, i.e. (I am not familiar with "allow-hotplug", but have left it):

```
allow-hotplug
iface eth0 net static
     address 10.0.0.2 (changed for each client)
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     broadcast 10.0.0.255
     gateway 10.0.0.1 (Ubuntu Router IP)
     dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1
```

Third remove the `dns-nameservers` stanza from the router interfaces file. It doesn't belong there.

Comment: Looking at `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.wlan0.leases` gave me the router ip 192.168.0.1. So I added `dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1` on each client and I removed the `dns-nameservers` stanza at the router. But `ping www.google.de` at the client gives me `www.google.de: Temporary failure in name resolution`. I also read about a DNS forwarding server such as bind9, but im not sure if I need this for my use case.

Comment: Ok never mind. I connected an other client to my Ubuntu router and it worked! So I think it has something to do with hypriotOS and the raspberry pis. Maybe cloud-init did set something up on first boot before I disabled it.